# Chart.js stacked column does not recognize the stack parameter, all in one column

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js, stacked

I following the example of Chart.js for a stacked colum graph
http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/stacked-group.html

But when I try to replicate for my graph... the stack parameter does not works. 
I use the version 2.4.
Here is my code

```
        var color = Chart.helpers.color;

        var barChartData = {
            labels:  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]<?php // echo ($asse) ?> ,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: '2016',
                    backgroundColor: color('#FCB441').alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                    borderColor: '#FCB441',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data:  [2,4,6,8,10,12,14] ,
                    stack: 0,
                },
                {
                    label: '2017',
                    backgroundColor: color('#FF0000').alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                    borderColor: '#FF0000',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    data:  [2,4,6,8,10,12,14] ,
                    stack: 0,
                },
                {
                    label: '3',
                    backgroundColor: color('#FFFF00').alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                    borderColor: '#FFFF00',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    data:  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] ,
                    stack: 1,
                },
            ]
        };
        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('Chart_<?php echo $this->id ?>').getContext('2d');
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData,
                options: {

                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                                stacked: true
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                                stacked: true
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

`});

Here is my graph:

[My Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhNBp.png)

I still don't get it where's my mistake, it seems like the demo code.
Thanks in advice.

Phil

Comment: The only difference I see is that demo uses strings for `stack` property, maybe there's some type check and values aren't converted to string?

Comment: I had tried both, string and integer type, same results

Comment: Grouped stacks were introduced in v.2.5.0. See in [New Features](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.5.0). That example you linked uses v2.7.2.

Comment: O my god... thanks man...
I'm just an idiot... I changed the version, now it works.
>.<